# element modification during python list iteration

Tags: python

Could anyone, please, explain what exactly happens in the following code to the "element" during iteration?

```
array = [2,3,4]
for element in array:
    element = 3
print(array)
```

> > > `>>>[2, 3, 4]`

Output is [2, 3, 4]
    instead of [3, 3, 3]

Did I understand it correctly that when using "for element in l" syntax, we can only reference but not modify each element of an array of what does happen here?

P.S. I've seen the question named "why shouldn't you iterate like 'for element in array' ", but I couldn't find that one, so I asked it in this way. Seems like I found one of the disadvantages of iterating in this way. Please, redirect me to the mentioned question if possible.

Comment: its not even a reference, its more accurate to think of it as an assignment. so, `element = array[0] `for the first pass. after that, you just rebind the `element` name to something else. `array` has no reason to change.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

In the above example any changes to variable element in the loop is not possible.

**Code**

To get your expected output try this:

```
array = [2,3,4]
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = 3
print(array)
```

Comment: What do you mean "iterator is immutable during a for-loop", that's not true if I am understanding you correctly

Answer (score 0):

When the iteration start element variable already has the current value in the array. when you assign 3 to it it will contain it until the next iteration when it will again take the current value of the array and so on. 
To get [3, 3, 3] you need to do it as the following:

```
array = [2,3,4]
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    array[i]=3
print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `element` is a local variable in the scope of the `for` loop.

Run this snippet. I hope it can be self-explanatory (I used `e` instead of `element`), also I used [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index:

```
array = [2,3,4]
for i, e in enumerate(array):
    print('i =', i, 'e =', e)
    e = 100
    print('e = 100-->','e =', e, 'but array[i]=',array[i])
    array[i] = e
    print('array[i] = e --> array[i]=',array[i])
    print('-'*10)

print(array) #=> [100,100,100]
```

---

**Quick explanation**

`e` and `i` are local variables which receive the value of the element and the index of the `array` at each iteration.
Inside the loop you can change the value of `e` but it doesn't affect the the `array`. To change the value inside the `array` it is required to access it by index (`array[i]`).

Comment: For loops do not create a scope. Scope is irrelevant here. It's a red herring